# Add background color to Excel rows generated by DocX4J

Tags: java, excel, docx4j

I'm using DocX4J for creating an excel file. Now I want to give **some** rows a background color, depending on a calculation done before creating the excel.
However, I can not find a method or something to add a backround color for a row.
The Java-Doc is also not very helpful.
I thought about coloring each cell, but cells also don't have a proper method. (They don't have any proper-named methods at all ...).

Anybody knows a hint? It is really difficult to find  some documentation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a row element to worksheet/sheetData, for example:

```
    <row r="2" s="1" customFormat="1" />
```

and corresponding entries in the styles part. Look at fills, cellStyleXfs, cellXfs.

You can research these by looking them up in the spec, at http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/SpreadsheetML/index.html

When you are ready to code, you can [upload an xlsx](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html) which contains whatever it is you want, then click to have code generated for you.

In short, your best approach, once you have a basic understanding of Open XML parts and docx4j's JAXB based approach to them, is to use the code generator, and the spec, and beyond that, docx4j's source code.

Comment: Okay, I do not understand how to link a style to a cell using the API.